# jQuery Ajax() can't reach C# Webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I don't get why $.ajax() function cannot reach my [WebMethod].

Here is the jQuery below:

```
$('.BasketUpdaterSubmit').click(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Ajax/AjaxCalls.aspx/UpdateAsyncBasket',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{'name' : 'Ivan'}",
    success: function(data) { alert(data); },
    error: function(xhr) { alert("Damn!"); }
});
```

Here is the C# code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string UpdateAsyncBasket(string name)
    {
        // random stuff
        return "Received : \t " + name;
    }
```

When I place a breakpoint on the return statement I never seem to get there. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you statically access `/Ajax/AjaxCalls.aspx/UpdateAsyncBasket` (In a web browser ?)

Comment: your json also doesn't seem to be valid json, does ASP care that it isn't valid json? (single quotes should be double)

Comment: Does your `click()` event actually execute?

Comment: try `UseHttpGet = false` before `ResponseFormat.Json`

Comment: This may sound like a silly Q. Though is `BasketUpdaterSubmit` and ID or a class? If it is indeed an ID it should be `#BasketUpdaterSubmit` and not `.BasketUpdaterSubmit` othersize jQuery will not fire.

Comment: @mtashev: Can you please confirm whether my answer is working or not for you. I'm going to delete it since i don't want to reduce my points. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16568731/880434

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal > I've upvoted your answer and copied the solution. Delete it. Once i have access to my code i will try it out.

Comment: @karthikr Yes. I can access it.

Comment: @Ilia G Click is working. Errors are alerting.

Comment: @DotNetDreamer Will try this out when i have access to my code again.

Comment: @Darren Nah, the problem isn't there. I've tried both.

Comment: @Kevin B  Tried with double. No difference.

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug and examinig the actual response - you will get a message saying more or less what the actual problem with the request is...or at the very least examine the `xhr` object and see what the responseText is.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the experience I've had with this stuff, I THINK the JS has to be put inside inside .NET's page load javascript function to access C# web methods.

`function pageLoad(sender, eventArgs) { }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
$(document).on("click",".BasketUpdaterSubmit",function(){    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Ajax/AjaxCalls.aspx/UpdateAsyncBasket',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'name' : 'Ivan'}",
        success: function(data) { alert(data); },
        error: function(xhr) { alert("Damn!"); }
    });    
});
```

And the web.config you have to add following section inside the `system.web` section

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Above code should work(tested in my machine). My best suggestion for you is create a web service for this. so you can omit the page life cycle. 
You can refer following sample to learn how to do it properly
http://tutorials.cmsnsoftware.com/2011/01/how-to-call-csharp-function-in-ajax.html

Answer (score 1):

Try a `GET` instead of a `POST`.  I have a few web methods that work fine using similar javascript, but have decorated the method with this instead of just `[WebMethod]`:

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
```

And then make sure your ajax call specifies GET:

```
$('.BasketUpdaterSubmit').click(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Ajax/AjaxCalls.aspx/UpdateAsyncBasket',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{'name' : 'Ivan'}",
    success: function(data) { alert(data); },
    error: function(xhr) { alert("Damn!"); }
});
```

Comment: Will try this immediately once i have access to my code again.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out what's going on.
It seems that there is a default ajax setup function which was interfering with my jquery function and didn't proceed when testing. Most probable reason is improper parameter handling.
Sorry for the late response. Thank you all.